# How to grep '*' in unix korn shell

Tags: shell, unix, grep, pattern-matching

I'm trying to find something in a file with a pattern using the '*' but is not working, any idea how to do this?

this is what I'm trying to do:

```
grep "files*.txt" $myTestFile
```

is not returning anything, it's suppose that "*" should be all.

Comment: yeah, work as grep 'files*' $myTestFile but not with .txt at the end

Comment: Do you mean it literally needs to match `files*.txt`, or could it also be, say, `filesfoo.txt`? And do you mean `.` in the glob sense where it only matches a literal `.`, or in the regex sense where it matches any character? For that matter, do you mean the `*` in the regex sense where it means "0-or-more `s`s", or in the pattern sense where it means "match anything"?

Comment: Nothing ksh-specific here, btw, except inasmuch as you're using a shell that follows POSIX expansion rules using `$myTestFile` without surrounding quotes is buggy (try passing a filename with spaces that way). The behavior of `grep` is defined by your operating system, not your shell -- telling us which shell you have doesn't provide many clues about which `grep` you have.

Comment: I'm using Korn shell on SunOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `grep` doesn't support extended regular express, but **grep -E** or **egrep** do.

> egrep "files.*\.txt" $myTestFile

or

> grep -E "files.*\.txt" $myTestFile

In addition, three variant programs `egrep`, `fgrep` and `rgrep` are available.  `egrep` is the same as `grep -E`.  `fgrep` is the same as `grep -F`.  `rgrep` is the same  as  `grep -r`.   Direct
       invocation as either `egrep` or `fgrep` is deprecated, but is provided to allow historical applications that rely on them to run unmodified.

```
Matcher Selection
       -E, --extended-regexp
              Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression (ERE, see below).  (-E is specified by POSIX.)

       -F, --fixed-strings
              Interpret PATTERN as a list of fixed strings, separated by newlines, any of which is to be matched.  (-F is specified by POSIX.)

       -G, --basic-regexp
              Interpret PATTERN as a basic regular expression (BRE, see below).  This is the default.

       -P, --perl-regexp
              Interpret PATTERN as a Perl regular expression (PCRE, see below).  This is highly experimental and `grep -P` may warn of unimplemented features.
```

Comment: Solution from Jonathan and Jiangty works for me! thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to match the *exact string* `files*.txt`, that would be:

```
# match exactly "files*.txt"
grep -e "files[*][.]txt" "$myTestFile"
```

...or, more simply put using `fgrep` to match only the exact string given:

```
# match exactly "files*.txt"
fgrep -e 'files*.txt' "$myTestFile"
```

`[*]` defines a character class with only a single character -- the `*` -- contained, and thus matches only that one character. Backslash-based escaping is also possible, but can have different meanings in different contexts and thus is less reliable.

---

If you want to match any line that contains `files`, and later `.txt`, then:

```
# match any line containing "files" and later ".txt"
grep -e "files.*[.]txt" "$myTestFile"
```

`.*` matches zero-or-more characters, and is thus the regex equivalent to the glob-pattern `*`. Likewise, whereas in a glob pattern `.` matches only itself, in a regex `.` can match any character, so the `.` in `.txt` needs to be escaped, as in `[.]txt`, to prevent it from matching anything else.